# Issues connecting to a pix 501 via console cable

Tags: cisco-pix

Have a pix 501 that was set up to do filtering and I was working on setting the vpn up when I lost ssh connectivity. Looking at the front, all 4 lan lights blink intensely green but in a very repetitive pattern. The funny thing is there are only 3 devices connected to the 4 ports so that's the first element that doesn't look right to me.

Console cable light doesn't turn on when cable is plugged in and have tried rebooting it many many times to see the bootup sequence with no result. Also, I cannot connect to it via pdm or console but the traffic is permitted through.

Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I could do or should I count it as dead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I want to make sure, did you say that you can see the boot up sequence? If so boot into what is called rommon mode. I believe on these devices you press escape early in the boot up. This way you can either blow away the flash or config or perhaps both.

If you are not seeing the boot sequnce I would check you power supply and the open the device and perhaps replace the memory. I have experience with the 506 and the 515e  series. But perhaps the memory has gone bad in the 501 check if it is removable. If so it should be sd memory like sd100.

-Greg

Comment: Thanks Greg. No, I don't see a bootup sequence at all. Where would I be able to find memory for it if that is the issue indeed?

Comment: If the 501 does have removable memory you should be able to find it at some small computer shops just look up sd-100 memory. If not the pix is dead.